# chrome extension javascript problem

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I started trying to write chrome extension and I'm having problem with simple function:

script inside "backgroound.html":

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changedInfo,tab){alert("a")});
```

`manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "ogys",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "description",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "background_page": "background.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://code.google.com/"]
}
```

I understand that an change on any tab would trigger the event but nothing happends.

Comment: It's better to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. Not sure whether an alert on the background page is even visible. You can open the console for the background page on the add-ons page, you will see the log messages then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html), you've defined the `backround_page` in the wrong place.

Move the `background_page` property definition **outer** from `browser_action` action in this way:

```
{
   "name": "ogys",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "description",
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
   },
   "background_page": "background.html",
   "permissions": ["tabs", "http://code.google.com"]
}
```